# Why does binary search tree tend to become unbalanced to the right?

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

This is from [Heap](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse373/13wi/lectures/02-04/12-pq-heap.pdf) lecture slide 8.

[image]
Add, peek, and remove make sense to me as to why those operations are O(log n)- traversing through BST cuts tree in half after each move. Can anyone explain the intuition behind the last sentence though, that "The tree tends to become unbalanced to the right"? Why not to left? To me, it should be balanced because of the law of averages, like that the frequency of elements less than the root should even out with the frequency of elements greater than the root over time. [Law of Averages](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/law-of-averages)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't overthink it. It's simply because of the `remove` operation which always goes to the far left element and removes it. After several of these operations, you would end up with the tree being "heavier" to the right of the tree, regardless of root node or anything else.

Even if you have an extremely high valued root node that tends to push newly added elements to the left, you'll still eventually end up with a subtree on the left that is "right-heavy".

Comment: Why does remove "always go to the far left element"? What if it was `remove(49); remove(9)`? Or this `remove()` always `remove(min())`? (And if this is the case then..)

Comment: @user2864740 The comment is specifically about a BST used as a priority queue.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Then that one statement (comment) ought to clear up the confusion - except for "PQ" at the very top such is never mentioned again in the question or reply.

Comment: @user2864740 The whole lecture is about priority queues, and there's only so much room on the slides.

Comment: Ahh I see you always remove from far left so of course you have an unbalanced tree to the right.